# How to use partial matching in if loop in google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In the problem I input some number of spreadsheets. I loop over these spreadsheets and find a particular sheet inside it. That said sheet have common prefix.
eg setup(xyz).
So only setup word is common. I just need to get that particular sheet. I know matchtype cannot be used here, please let me know the problem of the code.

Code:

```
function myFunction() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1KBA8TwFNX1BrJtTWSiydtDL");
var sheets = ss.getSheets();

if (sheets.length > 1) {
  for( var i in sheets){
    if((sheets[i].getName()).MatchType.ANY == "setup(")
      {Logger.log(sheets[i].getName());
       Logger.log("hello");
      }
  Logger.log("hello");
}
```

}

}

Comment: Adding to the question. I need to access the sheet using getSheetByName. But again I need to access it by partial matching........... .eg `var sheets = ss.getSheetByName("setup(")` . @Zig Mandel –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MatchType has never been in javascript. Simply use `getName().indexOf("setup(")>=0`

Comment: Shouldn't it be >-1  instead of 0  ?

Comment: over -1 is the same as over or 0 for integers. if i must hardcode a value i prefer zero

Comment: if the match is on first character then indexOf() will return 0, so I think it should be >0 (strictly greater than 0) and not >=0. Am I wrong ? [The doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/String/indexOf) specifies it returns -1 if no match is found

Comment: Whats the problem with a match on the first character? Still is a prefix

Comment: you're right... it's indeed a prefix ;-) ... Let's say I didn't say anything ! (hum hum...) I was actually wrong :-D

Comment: Interesting that the other answer thought the same as you which i flagged and motivated me to add an answer.

Comment: Actually you used both :)  first you used > -1 then used > 0 (>=1 like the other answer )

Comment: I should never try to discuss with you, you are always right ;-))  How could I  imagine it could be different...? I swear I'll never try again ! cheers ;-)

Comment: No please do! I kept thinking you knew something that i was missing. Ive made that index mistake enough times to have it now embedded in my brain.

Comment: Adding to the question. I need to access the sheet using getSheetByName. But again I need to access it by partial matching........... .eg `var sheets = ss.getSheetByName("setup(")` . @Zig Mandel

Answer (score 0):

Where did you got MatchType? Never seen that, but you can use:

```
if( sheets[i].getName().indexOf('setup(') >= 0 )

if( /setup(/.test(sheets[i].getName()) )

if( sheets[i].getName().match('setup(') )
```

Comment: ...when match is on first character.